# How can I create a TcpSocket and TcpStream in the same MIO event loop?

Tags: rust, mio

Can I create the same server as `Server` or `Client` with different sockets?

Like `A ->  B ->  C`

Here, A is a client of server B, B is a server to A but a client of server C.

How can I register both of these in the same [MIO](https://github.com/carllerche/mio) [event_loop](https://wycats.gitbooks.io/mio-book/content/the_event_loop/README.html)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is expected that you [show that you tried something](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), whether it is a (**minimal**) snippet of code that doesn't work or links to research you have done. SO isn't a service where people write code for you.

Comment: Related [post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/mio-can-anyone-explain-me-mio-with-diagram-please/3822) from you on users.rust-lang.org. Have you checked out the examples in the mio-repository? There's the [echo server example](https://github.com/carllerche/mio/blob/master/test/test_echo_server.rs). It's self-contained and can probably be used as a starting point.

Comment: AFAICS, The echo server example is event based with all events originating at the client. The server can only send messages in response to a client message. I don't think this model works well for an IRC server or a computer game, so it doesn't probably cover Harrys example. 

Is it possible to separate a net::TcpStream in to a Sender and a Receiver that can be connected to mio separately?  Or do you need two TcpConnections? (If someone has an answer, please write it here. I would also like to know.)

Comment: Reply to self. mio-websockets seems to be aimed at the usecase. See this example from rust-chat.

https://github.com/nbaksalyar/rust-chat/blob/master/src/main.rs

Comment: i have tried to refer that echo server example. but i get problem when i tried to access event of SERVER B (TcpStream).